# Travis: different `script` for different branch?

Tags: travis-ci

I'd like to setup deployment based on branches using Travis-CI and Github.

I.e. - if we made build from `develop` - then exec `/deploy.rb` with DEV env hostname, if `master` - then `./deploy.rb` with PROD hostname and so on.

Only one idea I found - is to check `$TRAVIS_BRANC` variable and then execute script, like:

```
language: php
install:
  - true
script:
  - test $TRAVIS_BRANCH = "develop" && ./ci/deploy.rb envdev.tld 
  - test $TRAVIS_BRANCH = "master" && ./ci/deploy.rb envprod.tld
```

But this solution looks a bit weird as for me. Any other possibilities to realize that?

Any tips/links appreciated.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Travis-CI always creates builds based on the `.travis.yml` in the branch you are pushing. As a solution, you could thus maintain different `.travis.yml` files in the different branches.

If you regularly merge between the branches, this could however lead to inadvertent changes between the branches (if you merge the changes of the `.travis.yml` of one branch over to the other). If this is a concern, your solution is probably safer.

To ensure that only specific branches (e.g. `develop` and `master`) are built, you can [whitelist](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/customizing-the-build/#Whitelisting-or-blacklisting-branches) the branches in your `.travis.yml`.

When using your existing solution, you could simplify your `travis.yml` script though. It probably makes sense to move the logic for selecting the correct deploy target into your `ci/deploy.rb` script (or even add a separate wrapper script which you call from the `.travis.yml`). That way, you have only one `script` line in your `.travis.yml` which don't even needs to change if you change deployment targets.

Alternatively, to ensure you have no failing tests with your existing structure, you could even use something like this:

```
script:
  - if [ "$TRAVIS_BRANCH" = "develop" ]; then ./ci/deploy.rb envdev.tld; fi
  - if [ "$TRAVIS_BRANCH" = "master" ]; then ./ci/deploy.rb envprod.tld; fi
```

Comment: Shouldn't "$TRAVIS_BRANCH" = "develop"  be instead "$TRAVIS_BRANCH" == "develop" ?

Comment: Or the = is better for POSIX compliance?

Comment: The `test` command (which is normally called with `[`) specifies the `=` "operator" only. The `==` operator is a bashism which ca be used equivalently in Bash when using the `[` shell builtin or an executable with some equivalent compatibility patches. To not be dependent on Bash or compatibility patches, you should use the `=` operator instead.

Comment: Right, not depending on bash only is better.

Answer (score 2):

Seems that the best solution now is to use [stages](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/conditional-builds-stages-jobs/). You can have something like:

```
stages:
  - name: deploy
    # require the branch name to be master (note for PRs this is the base branch name)
    if: branch = master
```

See [Travis documentation](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/build-stages/) for more detail regarding stages.

Comment: I wish the example showed how to do this for multiple branches. How should another if clause or an else clause appear?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a much better solution because it's so simple.

Let's say you have a dedicated production branch (master) and a staging/testing branch (dev).

In your TravisCI account, you can set environment variables. You can choose to have certain variables only available for specified branches.

So, for example, in your `.travis.yml`, you write: `firebase deploy --project "$DEPLOY_TARGET"`

And set `DEPLOY_TARGET` (no dollar sign preceding var needed in the web config area!) as a different environment variable for each branch. Although that specific example works for firebase hosting, you could generalise the example with a script to act based on the branch env vars.

So you could set `$BRANCH_SPECIFIC_VAR` as an environment variable and specify each branch that you need, and then access that variable from your config file.

I hope this helps.